# flask installed but ... not installed

Tags: python, flask, pip

I´m trying to install flask (PC, Windows, VS Code). Even when pip runs ok, and apparently the package is installed, I get the "module not found" message from Python.

This is what I have done so far:

First, uninstall for safety:

```
PS H:\Mi unidad\Projects\Webserver-raspi-V2> pip3 uninstall flask
Found existing installation: Flask 2.0.2
Uninstalling Flask-2.0.2:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask-2.0.2.dist-info\*
    c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\*
```

Then, reinstall:

```
PS H:\Mi unidad\Projects\Webserver-raspi-V2> pip3 install flask
Collecting flask
  Using cached Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from flask) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from flask) (8.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from flask) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from flask) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from click>=7.1.2->flask) (4.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from click>=7.1.2->flask) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=7.1.2->flask) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=7.1.2->flask) (3.10.0.0)
Installing collected packages: flask
Successfully installed flask-2.0.2
```

After that, check install status:

```
PS H:\Mi unidad\Projects\Webserver-raspi-V2> pip3 show flask
Name: Flask
Version: 2.0.2
Summary: A simple framework for building complex web applications.
Home-page: https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\users\gp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: click, itsdangerous, Jinja2, Werkzeug
Required-by:
```

and, then, when trying to use it from Python (same error when running from VS Code):

```
PS H:\Mi unidad\Projects\Webserver-raspi-V2> python3 -c "import flask"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that if you have installed the packages in the global environment, you should have no problem, but I had my python packages installed as a user.

You can solve this by adding my user's python dir to myapp.wsgi file.
As an example:

```
sys.path.append('/home/deployer/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
```

Comment: Thanks! That would be the equivalent of adding the dir to my Windows PATH environment? I´ve just found that I have both python 3.7.9 and 3.8.10 installed. I guess that I should uninstall both and install only the latest version.  Or, as I plan to use virtual environments from now on, just install Python info each docker container. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: Yes Virtual environments are best practices